# Coloring a series of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, colors, computer-science

What I want to achieve is to color the series of numbers in a defined RGB range. Are there some algorithms for such a task? There are many articles about coloring graph vertices (NP-problem), but my goal is to assign an RGB color for each value in a series of numbers of relatively small size (<1000).

For example, to color such a series in a range from *RED* (255, 0, 0) smallest to *GREEN* (0, 128, 0) greatest, with an assumption that the function *generate_colors* does the task (RGB values are an example one, I took them from a palette just to show what I want to achieve):

```
    >>> numbers = [1, 107, 200, 450.3, 500]
    >>> generate_colors(numbers)
    [(255, 0, 0), (255, 153, 51), (255, 255, 0), (102, 204, 0), (0, 128, 0)]
```

For now, I see only a way of defining a delta between *min* and *max* values and implement something like a gradient descent with a step of the delta size. But what, if the data will be so unbalanced, that almost all the values will be much greater than a median? For instance, 10 values in a range of *1-30* and 200 values in a range of *30 000-50 000*. In this case, I think, there should be a way to create a weighting rule for the values, so colors from the upper half of the median (from the example) will receive more distributed colors that lower half. Because of that, I decided to check if there are any developed algorithms for such a task, so not to reinvent it myself.

Comment: Your question contains a lot of details, but I think in summary you want to take a sorted list of numbers and map them from 0 (min) to 1 (max) such that the result is more equally spaced than the input. (You can pick a color along a line in some color space afterwards). It's not obvious to me what makes a satisfactory solution for you. For example is it ok to map the i'th number in the list to i/(N-1) where you have N numbers? You say that mapping number x to (x-MIN)/(MAX-MIN) can be too unbalanced, but perhaps a weighted average of that and the index method would look satisfactory?

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for the reply! The idea of the even distribution of colors is the simplest one, but also it's least informative for the end-user. If we can keep color distribution in the way that the densest cluster of numbers (let's suppose we can identify clusters like in a question example) gets the widest color range so the colors will be easier distinguished on a visual UI component that uses them. Your idea with the weighted average is great, I will think about it further and will share my solution when I reach it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers.  Assign colors via a binary search.

That is, take your list of numbers.  Divide them in the middle.  Those above the median get one range of colors, those below get another.  If there is a median element, it gets the median color.

Repeat on each side.

Two side notes.  The first is that red to green is a poor choice.  About 5% of people have red-green color-blindness.  The second is that you'll get a much wider range of colors to use if you trace a 3-d path through the color wheel.  (You'll need to play around with it to see what works well for you.)